# Get sid, SQL query in active processes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Currently to view currently running processes in Oracle, I use the following command:

```
select s.sid, s.serial# 
from v$session s 
join v$process p on s.paddr = p.addr
```

Is there a way in that query to join to get the `sql_query` that is running for each of those processes as well?

Comment: I’m not sure what `sql_query` refers to but queries are associated with sessions, not processes. The currently active query for a session can be looked up using `v$session.sql_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course using `v$active_session_history` (Starting 11g), it give you lot of information about the queries running for the process.

The below query will give you the last executed queries (using order by desc on `sql_exec_start`) that is being happening on the database. I specified the columns in the select could help you. by the way `top_level_sql_id` its useful in case your query is being running by a procedure then youll know which procedure is executing it.

```
selecT ar.sql_text,
       ash.session_id,
       ash.SESSION_SERIAL#,
       ash.sql_id,
       ash.top_level_sql_id,
       ash.sql_plan_operation,
       ash.sql_exec_start,
       ash.event,
       ash.blocking_session,
       ash.program,
       ash.module,
       ash.machine
  from v$active_session_history ash
inner join v$sqlarea ar on ar.sql_id=ash.sql_id
order by sql_exec_start desc
```